Update column value based on mapping table
I have the following table
tab:([]exec_location_1:`PA1`DNS`DNS;quantity_s9:8 40 20;mf_quantity_s17:123 123 4;eq_quantity_s17:10 20 30)
and I need to update it with a new column quantity which is based on the following mapping:
orderQuantityMap:`NEW`XRM`PA1`PA3`PA4`PA5`XRT`XRB`MF1`DNS!(`quantity_s9`quantity_s9`quantity_s9`quantity_s9`quantity_s9`quantity_s9`quantity_s9`quantity_s9`mf_quantity_s17`eq_quantity_s17);
Im guessing this needs to be done as a functional update hence tried the following:
![tab;();0b;(enlist `quantity)!enlist(orderQuantityMap;`exec_location_1)]
which gives me the following result:

How do I update this so that the actual value of the column is pulled in to the quantity col?

Providing some sample input and output using q code instead of images would help a lot here. It's not clear to me what you want output.

edited, thanks. The quantity columns should display the value from the column thats listed

This is a basic version:
q)update quantity:{x y}'[select quantity_s9, mf_quantity_s17, eq_quantity_s17 from tab;
                         orderQuantityMap exec_location_1] from tab
exec_location_1 quantity_s9 mf_quantity_s17 eq_quantity_s17 quantity
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PA1             8           123             10              8
DNS             40          123             20              20
DNS             20          4               30              30

More dynamic version:
q)update quantity:{x y}'[(distinct value orderQuantityMap)#tab;
                         orderQuantityMap exec_location_1] from tab
exec_location_1 quantity_s9 mf_quantity_s17 eq_quantity_s17 quantity
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PA1             8           123             10              8
DNS             40          123             20              20
DNS             20          4               30              30

Technically you don't even need the index and can just use @':
q)update quantity:tab@'orderQuantityMap exec_location_1 from tab
exec_location_1 quantity_s9 mf_quantity_s17 eq_quantity_s17 quantity
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PA1             8           123             10              8
DNS             40          123             20              20
DNS             20          4               30              30

